# CSS Simple Thing doesn't seem to work

Tags: html, css, hover

I have the following CSS code:

```
.special {
    height: 20px;
    width: 125px;
    border-bottom: 0px #69D2E7;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    background-color: #69D2E7;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:"Arial Narrow",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 500ms;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    right: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 6969;
}

.special:hover {
    tranisition: opacity 500ms, border-bottom 500ms;
    opacity: 1.5;
    border-bottom: 200px #69D2E7;
}
```

I'm trying to make it so when hovered, it gets bigger (border-bottom height increases), and opacity changes. Opacity does, with the element I have, but the height doesn't increase. What am I doing wrong ?
http://jsfiddle.net/7U3xn/

Here's an example to see how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a [`border-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties#Border_Properties). For instance, you can use `solid`:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mYgR8/)

```
.special:hover {
    transition: opacity 500ms, border-bottom 500ms;
    opacity: 1.5;
    border-bottom: 200px solid #69D2E7;
}
```

Also, fix the typo as [MarcB points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341421/2680216). It should be `transition` not `tranisition`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tranisition: opacity 500ms, border-bottom 500ms;
   ^^---typo
```

Syntax errors in CSS blocks kill the rest of the css directives BELOW the error. If you'd bothered looking at your browser's developer console (e.g. shift-ctrl-J) in Firefox, you'd have seen the CSS error...